# Kubernetes NetworkPolicy limit egress traffic to service

Tags: kubernetes, calico, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Is it possible to allow egress traffic only to the specific service?
This is my naive try to do that:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all-egress
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53
    to:
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            k8s-app: kube-dns
    
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
```

Comment: "service" is not really an entity, but (with some CNI) iptable rules, so this is more virtual, that why NP always target pods

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I know you can do that only using `podSelector`.
However, if you have an access to cluster, I think you can still manually add additional labels for needed pods and use `podSelector`

[Create egress policies](https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/kubernetes-network-policy#create-egress-policies) provides you good template of `NetworkPolicy` structure. The following policy allows pod outbound traffic to other pods in the same namespace that match the pod selector.

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-egress-same-namespace
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      color: blue
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          color: red
    ports:
    - port: 80
```

I know that you can use [namespaceSelector](https://docs.projectcalico.org/security/kubernetes-network-policy#allow-ingress-traffic-from-pods-in-a-different-namespace) for ingress like below. Not sure you can use it with egress- havent tried. But to access to pods from other namespace you  should somehow  point it in the configuration

```
  namespaceSelector:
    matchLabels:
      shape: square
```